# Python - Read headers inside controller?

Tags: python, odoo, werkzeug, request-headers, odoo-10

I'm building `controller` between source control system and Odoo in a way that specific integrated code source control system (like bitbucket, github) would be able to payload data using json. Reading of actual payloaded data is working, but what I'm struggling, is reading `headers` data inside `controller`.

I need `headers` data so I could identify from which system this payload is received (for example data structure might be different in bitbucket and github). Now if I would read that `header`, I would know which system payloads the data and how to parse it properly.

So my `controller` looks like this:

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request


class GitData(http.Controller):
    """Controller responsible for receiving git data."""

    @http.route(['/web/git.data'], type='json', auth="public")
    def get_git_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Get git data."""
        # How to read headers inside here??
        data = request.jsonrequest
        # do something with data
        return '{"response": "OK"}'
```

Now for example I can call this route with:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://some_url/web/git.data'
headers = {
 'Accept': 'text/plain',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'type': 'bitbucket'}
data = {'some': 'thing'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Now it looks that controller reads headers automatically, because it understands that it is json type. But what if I need to manually check specific header data like `headers['type']` (in my example it was `bitbucket`)?

I tried looking into `dir(self)` and `dir(request)`, but did not see anything related with headers. Also `**kwargs` is empty, so no headers there.

**Note.**: `request` object is actually:

```
# Thread local global request object
_request_stack = werkzeug.local.LocalStack()

request = _request_stack()
"""
    A global proxy that always redirect to the current request object.
""" 
# (This is taken from Odoo 10 source)
```

So basically it is part of werkzeug.

Maybe someone has more experience with `werkzeug` or `controllers` in general, so could point me in the right direction?

P.S. Also in Odoo itself I did not find any example that would read headers like I want. It looks the only place headers are used (actually setting them instead of reading), are after the fact, when building a response back.

Comment: Have you taken a look over here http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#header-parsing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from openerp.http import request
```

Within your controller handling your specific path. You can access the request headers using the code below. (Confirmed Odoo8,Odoo10... probably works for Odoo9 as well)

```
headers = request.httprequest.headers
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw this in source code, but somehow thought it was meant for `http` routing type and I'm using `json` type. But it works regardless of type. It returns just what I needed.

Comment: Trust me, I hear you. I have done a LOT with controllers. The documentation really downplays what aspects of a request and response are contained where. I spent a huge amount of time trying to determine where a response object was located when I created a Facebook Chat Bot for Odoo.  The docs make it seem like you will find everything in **kw. That is only scratching the surface obviously.  Have a good one.